# Useful publications for computer scientists and software developers/engineers

Tags: computer-science

As a follow up to my previous question about ADC, I was wondering more generally if there are any good publications, free or paid, that are worth subscribing to in the area of software development and software engineering.  Which ones [have/do] you subscribe[d] to if any, and how are they?

I KNOW there are important publications in theory, so I will not ask the existential question there, but any recommendations?

Thanks in advance,

Mechko

Comment: How about both?
edit: apparently stackoverflow doesn't like the question :-p

Comment: Fair enough - I don't like the atmosphere there very much.

Comment: It depends on the time.  It seems now all the people who make their rep by calling out the small mistakes of others and their croney's are out on both sites right now :-p

Comment: should be made Community Wiki

Answer (score 1):

The technical nature of CS means that all the great resources are primarily RSS feeds.

I've not come across a programming magazine I would subscribe too, but I follow (far too) many rss feeds.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Dr. Dobb's](http://www.ddj.com/) an excellent resource (though not as excellent as reading articles on the web).

Answer (score 1):

[Communications of the ACM](http://cacm.acm.org/) is a classic publication

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of academic papers (or their abstracts) available through [Citeseer](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/). However full text often requires Athens/University login.

You may also be interested in flicking through [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.co.uk/) hits for your specific subjects.